# parsing key value in shell script

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file and want to look for value from that file using shell script.

So I'm trying to grep value using the below code.

```sh
VAR=($grep -Po "(?source-no": ")(\d+)" file)
```

but it's giving an error

> grep missing )

Data in the file looks like below

```
"source-no" : "123456",
```

Comment: `VAR=(...)` assigns an **array**, and `$grep` expands a **variable** with name `grep`. You never invoke `grep` in your code....

Comment: That looks like a snippet of JSON; use a parser like `jq` instead of `grep` (which relies on particular *formatting* to work properly). `jq -r '.["source-no"]' file` (or similar, depending on how deeply nested this particular name is in the JSON value).

Comment: @user1934428 I'm assuming the `$` and `(` got transposed, and the code is just `VAR=$(grep ...)`.

Comment: @chepner : Perhaps it was a typo, but in case it wasn't, I thought an explanation of how the command is interpreted would be helpful, to complement the answer by RavinderSingh13. Knowing how to do it right is one thing. Understanding the actual effect of the wrong attempt is IMO important too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Considering that you need to get digits as output, you could try following then. You are on right path, you need to fix 2 things here: correct your matching regex, where in look behind you need to fix `"` in it. Then to save it into shell variable: use `grep` command inside `$(grep command)` in this form.

```
grep -oP '(?<="source-no" : ")(\d+)' Input_file
```

To save this into a variable try following:

```
var=$(grep -oP '(?<="source-no" : ")(\d+)' Input_file)
```

Also try to keep shell variables name with small letters, which is recommended by experts IMHO.

---

***2nd solution:***

```
grep -oP '(?<= ")[\w\.]+(?=")' Input_file
```

`(?<= ")` match the pattern begin with, as `(?=")` match the pattern end with,`[\w\d\.]+` match the value you need that consist by word or digital or dot(.) which I guess the value pattern.

---

***3rd solution:*** OR using both positive lookahead and positive lookbehind here:

```
grep -oP '(?<="source-no" : ")\d+(?=")' Input_file
```

Comment: double quote `"` not need to escape in the single quote `'`

Comment: @VictorLee, Thank you, I was trying with `"` in grep hence I escaped it, changed it now.

Comment: Hello @RavinderSingh13, I have a similar situation. But I have a raw file instead of json file with contents:
`abc=aqb9xy.com` (next line)
`xyz=1234`. I tried your solution2 with changes: `var=$(grep -oP '(?<=abc=)(\d+)' Input_file)`. But this returned nothing. Can you please let me know what needs to be changed in my case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Preeti, this will work for same lines, what is your expected output here?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I am expecting output to be `var=aqb9xy.com`

Comment: @Preeti, if you have only 2 lines then try `awk -F'='  'FNR==1 && $1=="abc"{print "var=" $2}' Input_file`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 unfortunately file content is more and not restricted to 2 lines.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, using `$grep` is [variable expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Note that this part of the pattern `(?source-no": ")` is not a valid pattern, and it is also missing a space before the colon.

As you are using `-P` for Perl-compatible regular expressions, you can make use of `\K` to clean the current match buffer.

```
"source-no" : "\K\d+(?=")
```

- `"source-no" : "` Match literally
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\d+(?=")` Match 1+ digits and assert `"` directly to the right

For example

```
VAR=$(grep -Po '"source-no" : "\K\d+(?=")' file)
echo $VAR
```

Output

```
123456
```